# Setting Up PHP Class's without a framework

Tags: php, class

Does anyone have a guide or can provide me with a quick example how to set up a class and pass the data from the class to the index.php?

I was thinking I could do it like I do in a framework can I not?

`$this->class->function();`

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? Pass what kind of data?

Comment: For the record you can (and should) read a lot on this in the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**coolclass.php**

```
class coolClass
{
    public function getPrintables()
    {
        return "hello world!";
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
include 'coolclass.php';
$instance = new coolClass();
echo $instance->getPrintables();
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick example:

Foo.php

```
class Foo {
  public __construct() {
    ..initialize your variables here...
  }

  public function doSomething() {
    ..have your function do something...

  }
}
```

Index.php:

```
Include('Foo.php');
$my_Foo = Foo();
$my_Foo->doSomething();
```

I think its fairly straight-forward as to what's happening here...so ill leave it at that. Don't want to give too much away.